# Thread.sleep() not working

Tags: java, thread-sleep

Whilst trying to make a gamecharacter jump in java, I tried to use Thread.sleep() to make an image move up 5 pixels, then wait for e.g. 100 miliseconds, then move up 5 pixels again, etc.

Instead, when the image needs to make 5 steps up of 5 pixels each, and wait 100 miliseconds everytime, it waits 500 miliseconds and moves up 25 pixels.

I can't explain this behaviour and there doesn't seem to be an answer online. Note that my program doesn't contain threads. Here is my code:

```
ImageIcon poppetje1         = new ImageIcon("img/poppetje1.jpg");
JLabel    poppetje2         = new JLabel(poppetje1);

...

public void jump() {
    try {
        poppetje2.setBounds(poppetje2.getX(), (poppetje2.getY()-5), poppetje1.getIconWidth(), poppetje1.getIconHeight());
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

...

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            jump();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is enough of my code, if I should upload the complete code, please ask.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I suggest looking into "game loops" if you're doing this sort of programming. You shouldn't be having to sleep like that with this pattern.

Comment: You are sleeping on the event dispatcher thread, this is not good as it makes your user interface unresponsive and probably won't do what you want. You could use some kind a timer instead (for example, a java.swing.Timer). As suggested by David Ehrmann, you'd be much better off researching game loops or using a Java framework for games like libgdx or Slick2D.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I solved it using java.swing.Timer, and the program is running smoothly now : )

Answer (score 2):

Does `setBounds` include a redraw/render step? If not, blocking within `keyPressed` is probably preventing the redraw from happening until the sleeps are all done and `keyPressed` returns.

Comment: `setBounds` does not redraw, calling it X times in raw is the same as calling it once with the latest values. Which is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get an exception in this line of code `poppetje2.setBounds(poppetje2.getX(), (poppetje2.getY()-5), poppetje1.getIconWidth(), poppetje1.getIconHeight());` and it's jumping directly on the catch statement.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an error in my errorlog then? The code runs without errors, just not as expected.